# google cloud tomcat stack mysql access

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I created a tomcat stack instance on google cloud and it comes with mysql 5.5. I can access it through terminal by ssh then enter command line `mysql -u username -p`. However, I am trying to access the database through mysqlworkbench but I could not get the connection.

So, I guess I need to use connection method "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" and I need to confirm if I have the parameters right.

```
SSH Hostname: the IP of my instances <br/>
SSH Username: my google account username? this is the one i use to login when setting up the gcloud ssh<br/>
SSH Password: the password for the account<br/>
SSH Key file: ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine<br/>
MySQL Hostname: i put tomcat_rmre which is the hostname for the database when I do "show variables" in the terminal<br/>
MySQL Server Port: the port in "Show variables"<br/>
Username: username of the database<br/>
password: password of the database
```

When I test connection, I get `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Answer (score 0):

The [Tomcat Click to Deploy](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/tomcat) solution does not use Cloud SQL, it just includes MySQL running on Google Compute Engine.

If you are not able to connect to the MySQL instance remotely via the "Standard (TCP/IP)" connection method it is probably because of one of:

- You may have forgotten to [open TCP port 3306 in your GCE firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#addingafirewall).
- MySQL may not be listening to remote connections. Your my.cnf should contain `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and should not have `skip-networking`.